# The first part of this htaccess rule is working but the second part is not working

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

The first part of this htaccess rule is working but the second part is not working. I am attempting to create two blogs on a single site. So while viewpost.php collects data from one table in my database, `ss-viewpost.php` collects data from a completely different table. The `RewriteRule` enables the title slug to be at the end of the URL.

How can I fix this?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /tms/

RewriteRule ^c-(.*)$ catpost.php?id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^a-(.*)-(.*)$ archives.php?month=$1&year=$2 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ viewpost.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]


RewriteRule ^c-(.*)$ ss-catpost.php?id=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^a-(.*)-(.*)$ archives.php?month=$1&year=$2 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ss-viewpost.php?id=$2 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Well, you're matching the exact same urls on both. How would that work? It will obviously only use the first match. If not, how would htaccess know which rewrite rule it should use? You need different urls.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I changed the url rewrite but now only one is working at a time. How to work both at a time? Here is the updated code: http://textuploader.com/dfok9